# Javafx : TableCell focus lost

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, listener

I have  `TableView` and I want to do something when the cell loses the focus. 
I have cell selection enabled on this `TableView` and it doesn't listens to cell focus lost. I tried this way:

```
table.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null) {
            //doSomething
        }
        // else doSomethingElse doesn't work
});
```

Simply it doesn't listen when I deselect (Ctrl + click) the cell. What did I wrong or how can I listen to focus lost on a `TableCell`?

Comment: Is it cell *focus* you are interested in, or cell *selection*?

Comment: @James_D I'm interested in cell selection, to listen somehow to the selectedCell, but selection model doesn't have `selectedCellProperty`. It would be perfect if i could somehow listen to the selected cell(not focused, maybe I was wrong in the question). Do you have any idea how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
TABLEVIEW.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
        if (newPropertyValue) {
            System.out.println("on focus");
        } else {
            System.out.println("out focus");
        }
     }
});
```

It works only if you select another selectable element (doesn't work e.g clicking on a pane).

Comment: Surely that just observes focus on the entire table, not on individual cells. E.g. if the focus (or selection) moves from one cell to another, your listener won't be invoked at all.

Comment: I have also tried this way but it doesn't work when I want to deselect the cell, at `//doSomething` part I want to enable/disable a button depending on that the cell is focused or not. So sadly this wont help me :(

Comment: Yeah that's right. It only work if you select the table and then deselect

Comment: @Developer66 So what does this have to do with the question that was asked?

Comment: @James_D Sry I thought he is looking for this solution I suggested